# recursion hailstone sequence

Tags: java, recursion

the program  prints the length of the sequence, the largest number in the sequence, the longest sequence from one to the number and the number that has the longest sequences from on to the number. I have everything correct except for the function startNum(int n) that is supposed to return the number that has the longest hailstone sequences from one to that number "n".the code returns the incorrect number the correct answer is 9 because it has the longest sequence from 1 to 16 but the function starNum is returning 16

Comment: You call `hailstoneLen(n)` (other than `n-1`), so the recursion doesn't progress.

Comment: Why did you delete the code? Now we have even less information about your situation. The description you gave is vague / generic at best.

Comment: i had to update it sorry @meowgoesthedog

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the `n--` in the startNum function. At some point you're going to call startNum with `n=2`. Then at `val = n--;` n will be decremented to 1, and then you call your recursion with `n-1 = 0`. Your base case is `n == 1`, so if n is less than 1, then it will keep going infinitely - or until your stack runs out of memory, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

when n=2 hailstone(0) is called and a hailstone is not defined for 0.